# Parallel processing windows OS

Tags: r

I am new to parallel processing. I have read through "High performance and parallel computing with R" at CRAN. and have come to understand the difference between implicit and explicit parallelism and that of distributed computing vs embarransingly parallel problems and read about foreeach, multicore, snowfall,package doSMP (retired from CRAN) etc

I have windows as OS, unfortunatelly installing other OS is not an option.

I would like to explain the structure of my code as to ask your opinion on the possibilities to implement parallel computing. Package used is caret.

1/3 of my code is to a large degree sequential and not possible to parallelize and 2/3 is mostly iterative with limited sequentiality (results have to be communicated once at the end of the processes and some data has to be taken from prior sequential results to be used by the process), this corresponds to the training of a model embeded within a conditional expression below. (can use from 2 to 10 folds and repetitions).

```
train<-runif(nrow (X))<=0.80
folds=2 
repeats=5
myControl <- trainControl(method='cv', number=folds, repeats=repeats,    
returnResamp='none', returnData=FALSE, savePredictions=TRUE, verboseIter=TRUE,    
allowParallel=TRUE, index=createMultiFolds(Y[train], k=folds, times=repeats))
PP <- c('center','scale')


model1<-if(Model1!= "0")  train(X[train,], Y[train], method='bag', trControl=myControl,   
preProcess=PP) else 0
```

The whole code has to be repeated 50 times with only X changing.

My questions are below.

1. What would be the options in respect to packages needed to implement parallel processing using multiple cores from a windows OS. rParallel (seems to be one) doSMP another
2. Given the explained structure of 2/3 the code which seems to be paralletizable, would you be of the opinion to run it as an embarrasignly parallel problem or opt for R serial loops given the few folds and repetitions
3. How would you approach repeating 50 times the same sequence of code with one minor change. In parallel or using simultaneously different R instances (for example in baches). In this last case how would you combine the results of running multiple R instances.

Thank you

EDIT

Note that the package doSMP is built into the core build of Revolution R, so you don't have to install it from CRAN (for this reason, you won't find it on the package list). All you have to do is load it with require(SMP) revoIPC package is also necesary. This package does no compile on modern versions of gcc and hence has been archived, doSMP depends on it and therefore went to the archives as well. Unsure if you can or you can not download the mentioned packages from REvolutions without beeing a customer

Comment: Are you aware that recent versions of R come with a package "parallel" which has an excellent vignette?

Comment: No I was not aware the parallel package could be used by windows and included multicore, thank you

Comment: One issue with the implementation on Windows is that the multicore-like functionality is limited to a single sequential worker. Unsure how much of a gain would be. I guess I should move to another OS

Comment: Actually gains on windows are very impresive, thank you for your imput

Comment: Related questions: [Parallel for-loop in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10604555/320399)